# Find a list of Windows Services by given criteria

Tags: c#, linq, windows

My goal is to implement a method, which finds a list of Windows Services that match given set of criteria:

1. `SearchString`: A search string
2. `SearchServiceBy`: Could be `ServiceName` or `DisplayName`
3. `SearchOption`: Could be `Equals`, `Contains`, `StartsWith`, `EndsWith` or `Regex`
4. `SearchServiceType`: Could be `SingleService` or `GroupOfServices`

```
private List<ServiceController> GetServices()
{
    var allServices = ServiceController.GetServices().ToList();
    var resultList = new List<ServiceController>();

    switch (SearchOption)
    {
        case SearchOption.Equals:
            if (SearchServiceBy == SearchServiceBy.ServiceName)
            {
                resultList = allServices.Where(s => s.ServiceName.Equals(SearchString)).ToList();
            }
            else if (SearchServiceBy == SearchServiceBy.DisplayName)
            {
                resultList = allServices.Where(s => s.DisplayName.Equals(SearchString)).ToList();
            }
            break;

        case SearchOption.Contains:
            if (SearchServiceBy == SearchServiceBy.ServiceName)
            {
                resultList = allServices.Where(s => s.ServiceName.Contains(SearchString)).ToList();
            }
            else if (SearchServiceBy == SearchServiceBy.DisplayName)
            {
                resultList = allServices.Where(s => s.DisplayName.Contains(SearchString)).ToList();
            }
            break;

        case SearchOption.StartsWith:
            if (SearchServiceBy == SearchServiceBy.ServiceName)
            {
                resultList = allServices.Where(s => s.ServiceName.StartsWith(SearchString)).ToList();
            }
            else if (SearchServiceBy == SearchServiceBy.DisplayName)
            {
                resultList = allServices.Where(s => s.DisplayName.StartsWith(SearchString)).ToList();
            }
            break;

        case SearchOption.EndsWith:
            if (SearchServiceBy == SearchServiceBy.ServiceName)
            {
                resultList = allServices.Where(s => s.ServiceName.EndsWith(SearchString)).ToList();
            }
            else if (SearchServiceBy == SearchServiceBy.DisplayName)
            {
                resultList = allServices.Where(s => s.DisplayName.EndsWith(SearchString)).ToList();
            }
            break;

        case SearchOption.Regex:
            var pattern = new Regex(SearchString);

            if (SearchServiceBy == SearchServiceBy.ServiceName)
            {
                resultList = allServices.Where(s => pattern.IsMatch(s.ServiceName)).ToList();
            }
            else if (SearchServiceBy == SearchServiceBy.DisplayName)
            {
                resultList = allServices.Where(s => pattern.IsMatch(s.DisplayName)).ToList();
            }
            break;

        default:
            throw new ArgumentException("Unknown SearchOption: {0}", SearchOption.ToString());
    }

    if (SearchServiceType == SearchServiceType.SingleService
        &&
        resultList.Count > 1)
    {
        resultList = new List<ServiceController> { resultList.FirstOrDefault() };
    }

    return resultList;
}
```

Is there any better way to implement this?

There is no additional complex logic around the method invoke. The use case is simple: Wix Toolset Custom Action passes required parameters to the method, gets a list of services match the given criteria. So these services could be started/stopped further.

Comment: I think you would get some more useful help if you could include the entire class rather than only a single method. We then could see how this method is used in context.

Comment: The method is used from the Constructor, which requires all the listed parameters. I believe, there is no need in additional lines of code with the properties listing.

Comment: If Alex and Alexey are the same user, please request an account merge by a Community Moderator [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/contact).

Comment: I agree with t3chb0t that it's relevant how this code is meant to be used - otherwise, why not just directly filter the results of `ServiceController.GetServices()` with a Linq method call? And why does your method use properties instead of parameters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are my suggestions:

- Get rid of all the ugly and duplicate `if`s by replacing them with two dictionaries where each one returns a `Func`.
- Use `Regex` for all searching criteria by creating appropriate patterns or returning the `SearchString` if it's the pattern.

Example:

```
var propertygGetters = new Dictionry<SearchServiceBy, Func<Service, string>>
{
    [SearchServiceBy.ServiceName] => s => s.ServiceName,
    ...
}

var patternCreators = new Dictionry<SearchOption, Func<string, string>>
{
    [SearchOption.Equals] => s => $"^{s}$",
    [SearchOption.Contains] => s => $"{s}",
    [SearchOption.StartsWith] => s => $"^{s}",
    [SearchOption.EndsWith] => s => $"{s}$",
    [SearchOption.Regex] => s => s,
}

var getProperty = searchStringGetters[SearchServiceBy];
var createPattern = patternCreators[SearchOption];

var pattern = createPattern(SearchString);

return 
    allServices
        .Where(service => Regex.IsMatch(getProperty(service), pattern))
        .ToList();
```

*(warning: notepad programming)*